# Why do shed and brown poplar (Populus) leaves get an iridescent blueish colour when wet?

Tags: botany

When the brown leaves of poplars shed on the ground stay for a while under wet conditions (e.g. like in a puddle), they become a fascinating iridescent blueish colour, which is best seen when light shines on it. I tried to look this up, but did not get any results... any ideas?